# How can I add minor mark ticks to every even x value?

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to add some minor ticks to the x axis, but not in every value (too many!). So I thought I could add every 2 units. However, `minor tick length` seems to be ignored here.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
      xbar,
      xlabel={Number of dots},
      ylabel={Blue value},
      scale only axis,
      axis lines=left,
      xmin=0,
      xmajorgrids=true,
%      minor x tick num={2},
      minor tick length=2,
      enlarge y limits={abs=1},
      ]
      \addplot[draw=none, fill=green!30]
      coordinates {(0,0)(30,1)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And the graph:

[image: X Bar Chart]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `minor tick length` key controls the length (how big) the minor ticks will be and not the separation between them. In your case, it's not ignored; it's obeyed and converted to `2pt` (you can check this using a larger value such as `50`).

If you want to place minor ticks at even values for the x-coordinates, , you can use `minor xtick` as in

```
minor xtick={2,4,...,28}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
      xbar,
      xlabel={Number of dots},
      ylabel={Blue value},
      scale only axis,
      axis lines=left,
      xmin=0,
      xmajorgrids=true,
      minor xtick={2,4,...,28},
      enlarge y limits={abs=1},
      ]
      \addplot[draw=none, fill=green!30]
      coordinates {(0,0)(30,1)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Remarks

- `pgfplots` internally loads `tikz` so there's no need to load the latter explicitly.
- Using `[h]` for float placement is a recipe for disaster; use a less restrictive specification such as `[htp]` or none at all.